# Block size in subsampling and bootstrap for time series

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, bootstrap, standard-error, subsampling

I have a dependent variable, a time series of 80 periods (discrete decisions). I am doing maximum likelihood estimation with 10 parameters. Now I want to get the standard error or confidence interval of the estimates of these 10 parameters.

One feature of my likelihood function is that the decisions is determined by all the history of $x$, and the weight of past $x$ decreases geometrically: $x_t+\rho x_{t-1}+\rho^2 x_{t-2}$... where $\rho$ is one of the parameters needed to be estimated.

So I am thinking that moving block bootstrapping perhaps is not suitable to sustain the data structure, and I should use subsampling. But subsampling of a given block size leaves me a very few subsamples. For example, if I choose a block size of 40, I get only 41 subsamples.

Should I concern about it? Is it sufficient? Can I use multiple block sizes to construct a confidence interval?

Is there any other alternatives that I could use to get standard error or confidence interval?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two approaches based on the description of your problem.

1. Analytic solution of standard errors: If your likelihood function allows it (which may be the case based on the autoregressive structure of your series), you can estimate the standard errors as the diagonal of the *outer product* of the gradients of your likelihood function evaluated at the maximum Likelihood estimator. In your case, since you have ten parameters, the gradient $\nabla_{\theta} L(\hat{\theta},y_t)$ should be a 10 x 1 vector. Thus, the variance-covariance will be a 10 x 10 matrix, which can be estimated as

$$\Omega(\hat\theta,y_t) = \nabla_{\theta} L(\hat{\theta},y_t)\nabla_{\theta} L(\hat{\theta},y_t)^T $$
The standard error of the estimates would be the diagonal elements of this matrix.

Since autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity can be a feature of your data, you may want to use a Heteroskedasticity and Autocorrelation (HAC) robust var-covar estimate. See [These lecture notes and bibligraphy](https://web.pdx.edu/%7Ecrkl/ec575/ec575-3.htm#lm) for more details

2. The other solution would be to use Stationary Bootstrap to sample for a time series. This block-based method allows you to better preserve your data's time-series dependency and structure.

I hope this helps!

Comment: My likelihood function is a mixture model $L(p, \theta)=p\prod^T_tL(y_{t}(\theta)|type1)  + (1-p)\prod^T_tL(y_{t}(\theta)|type2)$, and $p$ and $\theta$ are parameters to be estimated. so I am not sure how I can get the gradients for each $t$ and apply HAC.

Comment: And do you mind explain a bit more about why stationary bootstrap can work? My concern about MBB was that, say the bootstrap sample is (1,2,3),(5,6,7),(6,7,8) etc with block size of 3, so the starting obs of each subsample, i.e., 5 and 6 in this example are guaranteed to have wrong history of $x$ and so likely predict wrong $y$ compared to original dataset. I think this argument can also apply to stationary bootstrap. Do you mind explain a bit more?